# CTN SuperStore Runtime error 75

Tags: windows, windows-2000

ive been using CTN SuperStore EPOS system for many years now and i have come across my major problem with it.

I am running the EPOS on Windows 2000 and when i try to start the SuperStore software i get the following error:

> SStoreStart
>
> Runtime error 75
>
> Path/file access error

Can anyone help me with this as my technical support company have gone bust!

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ive sorted it now. The Runtime error 75 originates from the Visual Basic source code that relates to permission problem. So i checked the shares on the server and gave them full read/write permissions and it worked after a reboot.